# How to create a simple maven project using m2e

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

How can I create a simple maven project using m2e ?

I just need to create simple java project but when I try to create a new maven project I have to select from multiple artifacts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maven archetype Plugin allows the user to create a Maven project from an existing template called an archetype. you can simply skip this step if you only need a simple java project in the project setup wizard:
[image]